# How to correctly structure nouns in parallel?

Tags: american-english, syntactic-analysis

I am currently writing a note in my thesis to thank my professor for his help, and want avoid him proofreading his own thank you note, so I want to get it right on my own (perhaps with a bit of help...)

I been told that when someone list things in parallel, the "thing" listed should be of the same word class.

So in a sentence like this

> I would first and foremost like to thank my supervisor, Prof. Ken for his patient guidance through this process and for being the best sparring partner for discussing, brain storming, and for willing to going through several drafts of the thesis.

...it would appear that the "...discussing, brain storming and for willing to..." should have been structured in a different way. Something about addressing things like that should may not entail different word classes, but should be of the same word class — in this case a verb, noun, verb should become verb, verb, verb.

Is that analysis correct?

Comment: Which part are you concerned about? Meanwhile, just a couple of notes: 1. your note looks like it's addressed to a third party, not to your supervisor; and 2. use "to go through" instead of "to *going through".

Comment: I've clarified the purpose of the note (enough for our purposes anyway), but you really do need to explicitly indicate exactly what you are concerned about in your sentence. We don't do proof-reading, but we are able to help with explicit questions. See "How can I ask about checking my text?" in [Help](/help/on-topic).

Comment: The .."discussing, brain storming and for willing to"... should have been structured in a different way. Something about addressing things like that should may not entail different word classes, but should be of the same word class... in this case a verb, noun, verb should become verb, verb,verb..

Comment: Thanks for that: I've added it to the question. I think it's on-topic (although I can't vouch for anyone else).

Comment: Expressions of thanks to or through third parties are very common.

This would be *I would first and foremost like to thank my supervisor, Prof. Ken for his patient guidance through this process and for being the best sparring partner for discussing* and brain-storming ideas and for being willing to go *through several drafts of the thesis.*